# Replacement in a While loop

Tags: replacement

I want substitute `m` for `n` in `n = -3; While[True, If[2 n^2 + n - 6 == 0, Break[]]; n += 1/2];n`

**Here is what I want.**

```
 m = -3; While[True, If[2 m^2 + m - 6 == 0, Break[]]; m += 1/2];m
```

I have tried this below.

```
{n = -3; While[True, If[2 n^2 + n - 6 == 0, Break[]]; n += 1/2]; n}/.n->m
```

Only get `{m}` in the output. it failed to get the result that I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are facing is caused by the order in which your code is evaluated:

```
{n = -3; While[True, If[2 n^2 + n - 6 == 0, Break[]]; n += 1/2]; n}/.n->m
(* --> *) {-2} /. -2 -> m
(* --> *){m}
```

As you can see, there are two issues:

- The code is on the left side of `/.` is evaluated before the replacement is made
- The left side of the replacement rule is evaluated before the replacement is made

One option is to use [`Hold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) and [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) as shown by @Nasser to control the evaluation. Another solution is to use [`Unevaluated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) and [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html):

```
Unevaluated@{
  n = -3;
  While[True, If[2 n^2 + n - 6 == 0, Break[]]; n += 1/2];
  n
} /. HoldPattern@n -> m
```

Here, `Unevaluated` prevents the left side from evaluating before the replacement is made. `HoldPattern` is used to solve the second issue, i.e. that the left side of the rule is evaluated, which could break the replacement rule if `n` already has a value. Two things to note:

- If you want to store the code into a variable, @Nassers solution is more suited, since `Hold` gives you better control over when the evaluation is happening.
- The `HoldPattern` part can also be applied to @Nassers solution for the case where you cannot clear `n`.

Comment: Removing `HoldPattern@` in your code is also working. But how can I get the output like this `m = -3; While[True, If[2 m^2 + m - 6 == 0, Break[]]; m += 1/2];m`?

Comment: The `HoldPattern` part is only needed if `n` has a value, otherwise it will work without, yes. If you want the actual code as output, you can use [`Defer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) instead of `Unevaluated`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
ClearAll[n, m];
code = Hold[{n = -3; While[True, If[2 n^2 + n - 6 == 0, Break[]]; n += 1/2]; n}];
```

[image]

```
code = code /. n :> RuleCondition[m, True]
```

[image]

And now you can do `ReleaseHold[code]` to evaluate it using `m` instead of `n`

Comment: how can I get the output like this `m = -3; While[True, If[2 m^2 + m - 6 == 0, Break[]]; m += 1/2];m`? I wanna view it.